# I am running this command and it is only running for first seven files in a loop can anybody tell. there are 212 images in the folder

Tags: python, csv

'''from PIL import Image
import glob
import csv

path=r"C:\Users\Hp\Untitled Folder\dataset\sunset*"

for file in glob.glob(path):

```
a=Image.open(file)
data=(a.filename,a.mode,a.size,a.height,a.width,a.format,a.info)
#print(data)
no = 0
print(no)

with open('su_image_scraping_.csv', 'w',newline='') as csvfile:
    
    fieldnames = ['Serial No.','path', 'mode', 'height','width','format','info']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    
    thewriter.writeheader()
    
    for data in data:
        no += 1
        thewriter.writerow({'Serial No.':no,'path':a.filename,'mode':a.mode,'height':a.height,'width':a.width,'format':a.format,'info':a.info})
        print(no)'''
```

Comment: for data in data:??? redeployment?

Comment: please fix your formatting issue above - use 3 backticks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.